# Show that every imaging f with certain properties is a group

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Let $f:\hat{C}\to\hat{C} $ a bijection with the property to sent lines an circles to lines and circles. Show that f is a group with operation the composition of functions (images) (whom obviously contains the Mobius transformations).
Sorry for the bad terminology,but I am new to algebra.
Can you help me? I showed that every Mobius is a group,but I can't think this clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common exercise in basic complex analysis so I will help you by outlining the steps of the proof:

1) Show that the class of functions of the form $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$ send lines to lines and circles to circles.

2) Show that every bijective map $T(z): \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ has the form $az+b$ with $a \neq 0$.

3) Extend (2) to show that any one-to-one rational map on the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is of the form $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$.

4)  Show that these linear fractional transformations form a group under composition of mappings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have only managed 1). I have not yet taken complex analysis yet I need some tools to do this. If you have some time please help me with the others.